# A hard VRP with Time Windows + Multi Routes

Tags: vehicle-routing, vrptw, multi-routevrp

I'm working on a complex VRP problem. I'm working on the generic case, but for you to understand better I've created a small instance....

Assume that there are 3 demand (D1-D2-D3) and 3 supply nodes (S1-S2-S3) all with its own time windows (WLOG in increasing order, so TW of D1 is earlier than TW of D2). Time windows are valid only when entering to a node. Each node should be visited at least once. There are 2 vehicles and they are parked in one of these 6 nodes (both cannot be at the same node at the same time). And there are no additional starting or ending depots. Starting point of the vehicle is where it is parked initially and in later routes it is on the node where it has visited last. The objective is minimizing the total distance travelled. You can assign random distances between nodes and random service times for each node. Each vehicle can do multiple visits.

Let's say initially vehicle-1 is in S2 and vehicle-2 is in D3. So a feasible solution can be vehicle-1 can do like route-1: S2-S1-D1-D2 and route-2: D2-S2-D3 and for vehicle-2 -> route-3: D3-S3... One crucial rule is before visiting a demand node in each route, the vehicle should visit a supply point, because vehicles are assumed to be empty initially and at the end of each route. Now here in route-1, the first visit from S2 to S1 is kind of forced and we should ignore S2's TW as it just leaving and we are obliged to obey only [image]S1,D1,D2's TWs.

How can we model this as a MILP?

Comment: You wrote for route 3 "D3-S3...". The ellipsis after S3 suggests the route would continue, but if the vehicle visited S3 within the time window [36, 37] wouldn't it be too late to visit any other nodes?

Comment: @prubin sorry for the "..." actually the route ends at S3 and there is no other node to visit after S3, so no issue about being late for other nodes.

Comment: There are a few more things to clarify. (1) Is this a single time period model (after every supply node gets visited we're done) or a multiperiod model (so where vehicle 1 ends up at the end of day 1 affects solutions for day 2)? (2) Do you have known travel times between nodes, or is travel instantaneous (in which case I'd like to invest in the technology)? (3) Is there a known nonzero service time at each node and, if so, does the time window mean arrive within the window, depart within the window, or both?

Comment: 1-For now single time period, but as you have highlighted at the end of the day the vehicles final destinations will probably be different than their original locations. For now we are just interested in the single period case.
2- Yes all travel times and service times are known. I've made up the window LBs and UBs, assume that service times and travel times are nice enough so that my solution is feasible.
3- TWs only apply for arrival. For example it is Ok to arrive at D1 at 15.99 and depart later than 16. So TWs are ignored for departure

Comment: Another question. Assuming that the rest of the solution fell into place, could V1 (starting at S2) just take an extended coffee break until time 24, load up at S2 and then go straight to D3 without having to stop at another supply node (as it does in your example solution)?

Comment: Yes that is possible as long as V2 can cover the rest of the nodes.

Comment: Supply/demand corresponds to a "pickup and delivery" component. Starting at different locations to a "multi-depot" component. Ending at the last node without returning to the depot to an "open" component. Then you need to look at how these components are modelled in the literature and assemble everything together.

Comment: You seem to want a lexicographic objective: first minimize tardiness, then minimize distance. In MILP, lexicographic optimization is better handled by solving one model for each objective and adding it as a constraint for the next one

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is a form of multi-vehicle routing problem with time windows (frequently abbreviated m-VRPTW, although I believe I've also seen MVRPTW). Searching for that will turn up a variety of references. One problem is that the "multi" part is ambiguous. Here it would mean both multiple vehicles and multiple "depots" (source nodes), but other people use it for just one or the other, or possible something else entirely. Some of those references may suggest MILP models.